# No decoder available for type 'audio/x-wma'

Tags: sound, 14.04, xubuntu

I'm using Xubuntu 14.04 LTS on my Lenovo R60e. I have installed ubuntu-restricted-extras and ubuntu-restricted-addons. When I try to listen this audio stream http://www.polskieradio.pl/st/program2.asx (it's my favorite radio station) in RadioTray 0.7.3 I get this error:

```
    0:00:06.845057510  2298 0xb3f056c0 WARN                asfdemux gstasfdemux.c:2068:gst_asf_demux_get_stream: Segment found for undefined stream: (1)
0:00:06.845142829  2298 0xb3f056c0 WARN                asfdemux gstasfdemux.c:3090:gst_asf_demux_process_bitrate_props_object:<asfdemux0> Stream id 1 wasn't found
0:00:06.845176090  2298 0xb3f056c0 WARN                asfdemux gstasfdemux.c:2068:gst_asf_demux_get_stream: Segment found for undefined stream: (4)
0:00:06.845206486  2298 0xb3f056c0 WARN                asfdemux gstasfdemux.c:3090:gst_asf_demux_process_bitrate_props_object:<asfdemux0> Stream id 4 wasn't found
0:00:06.877019093  2298 0xb3f056c0 WARN                asfdemux gstasfdemux.c:2416:gst_asf_demux_parse_stream_object:<asfdemux0> Unknown stream type for stream 4
0:00:06.879601156  2298 0xb3f056c0 WARN                asfdemux gstasfdemux.c:2068:gst_asf_demux_get_stream: Segment found for undefined stream: (4)
0:00:06.879760823  2298 0xb3f056c0 WARN                asfdemux gstasfdemux.c:2068:gst_asf_demux_get_stream: Segment found for undefined stream: (4)
0:00:06.879797089  2298 0xb3f056c0 WARN                asfdemux gstasfdemux.c:3452:gst_asf_demux_process_ext_stream_props:<asfdemux0> Ext. stream properties for unknown stream
0:00:09.352974562  2298 0xb3f056c0 WARN            uridecodebin gsturidecodebin.c:874:unknown_type_cb:<uridecodebin0> warning: No decoder available for type 'audio/x-wma, wmaversion=(int)2, bitrate=(int)128016, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)48000, channels=(int)2, block_align=(int)5462, codec_data=(buffer)008800000f0000000000'.
0:00:09.353145272  2298 0xb3f056c0 WARN              decodebin2 gstdecodebin2.c:3574:gst_decode_bin_expose:<decodebin20> No suitable plugins found
0:00:09.353182237  2298 0xb3f056c0 WARN              decodebin2 gstdecodebin2.c:3576:gst_decode_bin_expose:<decodebin20> error: no suitable plugins found
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks a lot for your help

Michal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst many of the audio players have now been upgraded to use the gstreamer 1.0 libraries which would normally play the `audio/x-wma` stream, radiotray has not.

To play `audio/x-wma` which your audiostream requires in ubuntu versions prior to 14.04 requires the library `gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg` to be installed.

Ubuntu 14.04 does not have this ffmpeg library in its repositories.

The easiest way is to install a PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```

As all PPA's you need to be aware of the "red-flags" as per the linked question below.

From a trust-worthy status, I've seen [webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/get-firefox-and-phonon-gstreamer-to.html) themselves promote this - thus it could be construed to be more widely used than some of the obscure PPA's available. [mc3man](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2208040) was also behind this "petition" on UF and as a result created his/her PPA.

---

Related Question

- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-fo)

Comment: Just to note on ppa - It contains quite a number of packages, users who enable the ppa should go to the ppa main page for some further info. In general there are 3 types, packages that aren't available in ubuntu at all, packages that fix some current bugs in 14.04 & newer versions of existing sources, several that are git/svn master versions. All packages are pretested by me, the git/svn master ones (mplayer, ffmpeg, mpv in particular) are pretested in a proposed ppa first before copying to the media ppa. Any issues or suggestions can be relayed via launchpad email & I'll address promptly